# ExtJS 4.2 - How to map array to a model field and display dynamically on a grid column?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have this json data:

```js
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'something',
  description: 'somethingsomething',
  customers: [{
    id: 1,
    username: 'cust1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    username: 'cust2'
  }]
}
```

While I have no problems displaying the first three fields on the gridpanel, I however have an issue retrieving the array object for the `customers` field. My model goes like this:

```js
fields: [
  'id', {
    name: 'name',
    sortType: Ext.data.SortTypes.asUCString
  },
  'permanent', {
    name: 'description',
    Type: Ext.data.SortTypes.asUCString
  }, {
    name: 'customers',
    Type: Ext.data.SortTypes.asUCString
  }, {
    name: 'username',
    Type: Ext.data.SortTypes.asUCString,
    mapping: 'customers[0].username'
  }
]
```

When I try to access `customers[0].username`, it only retrieves the ones on that specified index. Removing the index number returns `undefined` as I assume it is looking for what index to return from. How do I properly retrieve all of `customers: []` and display it to my grid where it is structured as:

```js
{
  xtype: 'gridpanel',
  store: oStore,
  viewConfig: {
    loadMask: false,
    enableTextSelection: true
  },
  hideHeaders: false,
  bodyBorder: true,
  columns: [{
    text: 'Customer',
    dataIndex: 'username',
    flex: 1
  }, {
    header: '',
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    itemId: 'remove-player-btn',
    width: 50,
    sortable: false,
    resizable: false,
    menuDisabled: true,
    items: [{
      icon: 'resources/img/x.png',
      tooltip: 'Remove Player',
      scope: oMe
    }],
    editor: {
      xtype: 'text',
      name: 'deleteRow'
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use convert function available in model.This convert function is used for some calculation purpose & map response data for our needs.For example I will map **username** as below:

```
fields: [
{
  name:'username',
  convert:function(value,model)
  {
    return model.data.customers.username;
  }
}
]
```

Use same technique for **id** field.Reply if any issues.

Comment: This worked! However, I did not map it via `model.data` but `model.raw` instead as the former was undefined.